# BoxUsage not updated

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-simpledb

I'm trying to check the box usage before and after insertion of some records. However, the values are the same: `0.0000071759`, which should be the box usage for listing the domain. Here's my code:

```
import boto.sdb

conn = boto.sdb.connect_to_region('us-east-1',
                                  aws_access_key_id='key_id',
                                  aws_secret_access_key='access_key')


dom = conn.create_domain('test_01')

domain_meta = conn.domain_metadata(dom)
print domain_meta.BoxUsage

for i in xrange(10):
    item_name = i
    item_attrs = {'a': i+1}
    dom.put_attributes(item_name, item_attrs)

domain_meta = conn.domain_metadata(dom)
print domain_meta.BoxUsage
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see where the issue is. The box usage is recorded in `conn.box_usage` instead.